# Android - ListView displaying different layouts for items

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a `ListView` which displays a list of items from database. So I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
if (mDiscussionsCursor != null && mDiscussionsCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.home_discussion_row, mDiscussionsCursor, FROM, TO, 0);
    mAdapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);
    setAdapter(mAdapter);
    setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

These items are chronologically ordered. I would like to put a separation line between every day, i.e., display all items from May 1, 2013, then a title 'May 2, 2013' followed by all items of that day etc.

I assume I can take my `Cursor` and copy it to Array with special cells representing the titles for the days and then use the method presented here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

However, this seems very wasteful practice to me in both space and time, and I am wondering maybe you can think of something more clever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about custom cursor adapter? You can extend cursor adapter(e.g. android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter) and try the same approach described at the article.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sub-classing the SimpleCursorAdapter and overriding its associated members from the tutorial

```
getItemViewType
getViewTypeCount
getView
```

If you have a look at the inheritance hierarchies of SimpleCusrsorAdapter and ListAdapter (ListView adapter), you'll see that they are both subclasses of BaseAdapter, and is therefore why this is possible.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

**EDIT**

It will probably not be as cut and dry as simply subclassing and overriding. You may also need to incorporate some of the code in the CursorAdapter parent class into your overrides, and

```
bypass calling super.method().
```

For example, here is CursorAdapter.java's getView override, you may need to

```
explicitly call bindView()
```

(ref: http://androidxref.com/4.0.3_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
    } else {
    v = convertView;
    }
    bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
    return v;
}
```

To use the xref source code repository, go to

http://androidxref.com/

select your api version, and then in

**"Full Search"**

type

**ObjectName.java**

and in the list to the right

**"In Projects"**

scroll down and select

**"frameworks"**

and it search (I find this the most direct and effective way to get what ya want).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I'll look into it. This will probably take some time. Thanks again. +1.